# Compiler adding unexpected artifacts to build folder

Tags: typescript

I am following along with this [Getting Started](https://tsoa-community.github.io/docs/getting-started.html) guide to install `tsoa` Per their instruction, I generate a `routes.ts` folder which is placed under `/build`:

```
/build
  /routes.ts
```

Now, in `/src/app.tsx`, I reference it:

`import { RegisterRoutes } from "/build/routes"`

I am now getting an unexpected directory structure in `/build` when I run `yarn run tsc --outDir build --experimentalDecorators`:

```
/build
  /build
  /src
    server.js
  routes.ts
```

It appears because of my reference to `"/build/routes"`, I am getting `/build` and `/src` copied into `/build`. What I want are just the contents of `/src` copied into build.

```
/build
  routes.ts
  server.js
```

I added `includes: ["src"]` into my `tsconfig.json`, but that doesn't work.

Is there something local I may have done to effect this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript outputs files according to the `rootDir` directory in `tsconfig.json`. If that isn't set, TypeScript by default figures it out by finding the common path of all input files. Since you have files in both the `build` and `src` directories, the common path is the directory which encompasses both of those folders and which also contains the `tsconfig.json` file.

You can't import files outside of that `rootDir` so manually setting it to `src` in `tsconfig.json` won't work in this case.

#### Solution:

If you set the routes files to output to the `src` directory by modifying `tsoa.json` and then importing from that route file, that will automatically set the `rootDir` to what you likely want it to be. That change in `tsoa.json` would be:

```
"routes": {
    "routesDir": "src"
  }
```

and the corresponding import in your `app.ts` file (after running `yarn run tsoa routes`) would be:

```js
import { RegisterRoutes } from './routes';
```

#### Alternatively:

In case you specifically want the routes file in the `build` directory, one other option would be to create a symbolic link from the `routes.ts` file into the `src` directory. You would then still import from `./routes` in your `app.ts`.

#### Further reading:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig#rootDir